# Javascript insert data into form's input's - Populate form with data

Tags: javascript, forms, input, get

What is the fastest - "performance" way to populate form in javascript.

I have this and its working, but I was thinking are there better or faster ways to do it?

```
async function PopulateUpdateForm(formID)
{
    var currentForm = document.getElementById(formID);  // Get the form   
    var resPrommise = await GetUserData();  // Get responce
 

     // Populate the Form
     await resPrommise.json().then(content => // Get the response content
    {
         if (content != null)
         {  
             currentForm['email'].value = content['email'];
             currentForm['firstname'].value = content['firstname'];
             currentForm['lastname'].value = content['lastname'];
             if (content['age'] != 0)
             {
               currentForm['age'].value = content['age'];
             }
             currentForm['phonenumber'].value = content['phonenumber']; 
         }
    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function PopulateUpdateForm(formID)
{
    var currentForm = document.getElementById(formID);  // Get the form   
    var resPrommise = await GetUserData();  // Get responce
 

     // Populate the Form
     await resPrommise.json().then(content => // Get the response content
    {
         if (content == null) return;
         ['email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phonenumber'].forEeach(x => 
          currentForm[x].value = content[x];
         )
         if (content['age'] != 0) currentForm['age'].value = content['age'];
  
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will this be faster and what are the pros?

Comment: it's faster to type, but not faster to run. The pros is that it's more concise/readable

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your way of populating your form, for readability, unless you use a reactive framework like React or Vue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I am using just vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do that. you don't have to manually set value, instead you can do it dynamically...

use this:

```
function PopulateUpdateForm(currentForm, data) {   
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
// Populate Form data by input Name
    var ctrl = $('[name='+key+']', currentForm);  
    switch(ctrl.prop("type")) { 
        case "radio": case "checkbox":   
            ctrl.each(function() {
                if($(this).attr('value') == value) $(this).attr("checked",value);
            });   
            break;  
        default:
            ctrl.val(value); 
    }  
});
```

}

and use it by calling

```
var currentForm = document.getElementById(formID);  // Get the form   
var data = GetUserData();  // Get responce data
PopulateUpdateForm(currentForm, data)
```

Comment: Thanks but does this have better performance than setting it manually?

Comment: Personally i am using this technique in my recent project and i noticed it little faster then manually(which i followed earlier). like when using modal for edit and there are many field in my form it took some time to render, and sometime i noticed little delay(millisecond) not always noticeable.

Comment: So, I personally like this approach. You should definitely try this..